# Spring boot application crashing on starting:Togglz: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find the FeatureManager

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

i'm using toggle feature with toggle dependencies but when i tried to bring up the services some times application startup is failing saying  could not find FeatureManger.

I followed server approaches but none of them worked well. in this post the issue been highlited by updating jar dependecy, even that also not working.

Please suggest if you have other fix available for this issue.

https://github.com/togglz/togglz/commit/22b20ef7c8758dc5deadf0a6c4726e8c8d73cf5c